# How to get total sum of product wise in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `product_master` and `party_master`.

Table `party_master` has these columns:

```
Total life sum assured
Term Insurance
Mediclaim
Top Up
P.A Policy
Traditional Insurance
Vehical Insurance
Fixed Deposit
SIP
```

Each column has numeric values. I want to write a query to sum all column values with product category. How can I get that with this query?

```
select 
    pk_pid, name, 
    sum() as portfolio_am 
from 
    dbo.product_master 
order by 
    name
```

How to achieve this? Please help me...

**********************update************************

screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `group by` and `join` as follows:

```
select product.pk_pid , product.name, 
       sum("Total life sum assured" + "Term Insurance Mediclaim" 
           + ... + SIP) as portfolio_am 
  from dbo.product_master product
  join dbo.party_master party on product.pkid = party.fk_column_name
 group by product.pk_pid , product.name
 order by product.name
```

**-- Update**

So, you have `product_master` table with all products and `party_master` table with one column per product.

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select product.pk_pid , product.name, 
       sum(case when product.name = 'Total life sum assured' then "Total life sum assured"        
                when product.name = 'Term Insurance Mediclaim' then "Term Insurance Mediclaim"        
                .......
                .......
                when product.name = 'SIP' then SIP 
           end) as portfolio_am 
  from dbo.product_master product
  join dbo.party_master party on product.pkid = party.fk_column_name
 group by product.pk_pid , product.name
 order by product.name
```

Total life sum assured
Term Insurance
Mediclaim
Top Up
P.A Policy
Traditional Insurance
Vehical Insurance
Fixed Deposit
SIP

Comment: sound as crazy i just want like Total life sum assured total from all party_master column with name portfolio_am with product name.

Comment: If you just want single column value then you can use `sum(clumn_name)`